# how do i use multiple columns of a df as input to a function?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

ihave a dataframe full of numerical values. and i want to apply a function (delta) it takes 6 arguements.

```
calls['delta'] = calls[['callput','underlyinglast','strike','yte','rfr','hvol90']].apply(delta,axis=1)
```

i keep getting the error

```
TypeError: delta() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'S', 'K', 't', 'r', and 'sigma'
```

i also tried a variant with lambda, but i keep getting the error. i think because its trying to apply the function to each individual value, instead of the row.

can i do this any other way? (without iterrows, its so slow, its a df with 500k rows)

Comment: The function expects 5 arguments but you use *6* columns. Which columns do you really want to use?

Comment: it needs 6 arguments, but its missing only 5 (its passing the one numeric value in each "cell" i think.

TypeError: delta() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'flag', 'S', 'K', 't', 'r', and 'sigma' is reported when i call the function without any input.

Comment: Have you tried `calls.apply(lambda row:delta(row.callput, row.underlyinglast,row.strike,row.yte,row.rfr,row.hvol90), axis=1)` ?

Comment: thnx! this worked. but the other solution looks cleaner.

Comment: I didn't propose a solution, I asked what did you try? Using `apply` is slow anyway because it has to evaluate one row after another. You'd get better performance if you wrote `delta` so it works with series, or used `assign`.  For example, instead of `.apply(lambda row: row.A + row.B,axis=1)` you can use `df.A + df.B` to get the same result. This allows Pandas to use vectorization when performing the operation

Comment: i tried .apply(lamda x: delta(x), axis=1)

the line you proposed did work. but using *row just makes it look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apply` with `axis=1` calls your function for each row, but with 1 parameter: the row as a `Series` object. So you either need to revise your function definition to take a single row instead of multiple parameters, or wrap your function call in a lambda function which extracts the values from each row and calls the function with them.

1. **Revising your function to take a single row** 
   Instead of this:

   ```
   def delta(S, K, t, r, sigma):
       # ...
   ```

   do this:

   ```
   def delta(row):
       S, K, t, r, sigma = row.tolist()
       # ...
   ```
2. **Wrapping your function call in a lambda function** 
   Instead of this:

   ```
   calls['delta'] = calls[['callput','underlyinglast','strike','yte','rfr','hvol90']].apply(delta,axis=1)
   ```

   do this:

   ```
   calls['delta'] = calls[['callput','underlyinglast','strike','yte','rfr','hvol90']].apply(lambda row: delta(*row), axis=1)
   ```

   (the trick there is to use `lambda row: delta(*row)` instead of just `delta`; `*row` basically "spreads" the items in `row` across the separate arguments  of `delta`)